# type mismatch error i dont know what to do

Tags: ms-access, vba

I keep getting a type mis-match error, and I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim UserLevel As Integer

If IsNull(Me.txtLoginID) Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Login ID", vbInformation, "Login ID Required"
    Me.txtLoginID.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Password", vbInformation, "Password Required"
    Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
Else
    If (IsNull(DLookup("UserLogin", "Accounts", "UserLogin='" & Me.txtLoginID.Value & "'"))) Or _
    (IsNull(DLookup("Password", "Accounts", "Password='" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect Login ID or Password"
    Else
        UserLevel = DLookup("UserSecurity", "Accounts", "UserLogin= '" & Me.txtLoginID.Value & "'")
        DoCmd.Close
            If UserLevel = admin Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Administrator"
    Else
         DoCmd.OpenForm "Sales"
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your IsNull with Nz:

```
 If Nz(DLookup("UserLogin", "Accounts", "UserLogin='" & Me.txtLoginID.Value & "'")) Or _
Nz(DLookup("Password", "Accounts", "Password='" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'")) Then
    MsgBox "Incorrect Login ID or Password"
```